# using re.split() to separate a string into list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using this code to separate words into a list. The while loop is used to remove any blank spaces that come up, they will be elements with just a ''.  The problem is even after I run the while loop there are still elements with just ''. I believe they are due to whitespaces and indentations. The while loop does get rid of about 2/3 of these spaces. Is there a way just to get the words separated? I don't want any blank elements because when I run a loop on them later I get a string index out of range when I reference `mylist[i][0]`.

```
str = fpin.read()
mylist = re.split('[ \n]', str)
i = 0

while(i < len(mylist)):
if mylist[i] == '':
    del mylist[i]
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Since no one mentioned it directly yet: The empty strings are from when two spaces are next to each other, and there's nothing in between. The answers below will tell you how to deal with that.

Comment: In general, in Python, it is usually recommended to make a copy of a list that has just what you want in it, rather than to loop over an existing list and delete things from it.  Simply using the `.split()` will eat up multiple whitespace characters, so you don't need this, but here's an example of how to make a copy with just what you want:  `newlist = [x for x in mylist if x]`

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your specifications, you don't need a regex here. You can just use the string's `split` method.

```
>>> mystr = 'This     is  \n my awesome    \nstring'
>>> mystr.split()
['This', 'is', 'my', 'awesome', 'string']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to split a white space separated string into list:

```
re.split(r'\s*', re.sub(r'^\s+|\s*$', '', input_string))
```

Another problem with your code is that, you should not use str as a variable name, because str is a built in function.